# Python while loop not working as expected

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

When I type "no" into the input I expected it to add 1 to "x", therefore ending the loop, but what happens is that it ignores it and does not add 1 x. Here is the code.

```
x = 1
password = ""

while x == 1:        
    # imagine there is some code here which works

    ans1 = input("\n\nTest a new password? ")
    ans1 = ans1.upper()

    print(ans1)

    if ans1 == ("Y" or "YES"):
        x = x
    elif ans1 == ("N" or "NO"):
        x = x + 10

    print(x)
```

It's the bottom if/elif statement that is not working. It should continue to ask for input again until the user says NO but this isn't working.

Comment: Your if-branch does nothing so you can throw it out. And you can break a loop with 'break'.

Comment: I liked that previous title. Added some 'mystery' to the question ;)

Answer (score 6):

You should use or that way.

```
if ans1 == ("Y" or "YES"):
```

Can be replaced with:

```
if ans1 == "Y" or ans1 == "YES":
```

Or:

```
if ans1 in ("Y", "YES"):
```

The bug comes from the definition of the `or` operator. When you do "Y" or "YES", it will return "Y" as `A or B` is defined to return A if A is not false.  Here, A is "Y" which is not a False value. So, it will return A="Y". If you do `if a == ("Y" or "YES"):`, il will be equivalent to `if a == "Y":`. Ok it's a bit tricky but it's how python works.

Moreover, your code is very strange. It's a very bad habit to exit a loop like that. Generally, we put a boolean value "looping" that is set to false when we want to leave the loop.

Here's how I would do your loop:

```
looping = True 
password = "" 

while looping: 

    ans1 = input("\n\nTest a new password? ")

    if ans1.upper() in ("NO", "N"): 
        looping = False
```

You can also use a construction with an infinite loop (`while True:`). Then, you call the instruction `break` to quit the loop.

Comment: What's the point in the looping variable? Why not `while True:` and `break`? I wouldn't say your solution is 'typical Python'

Comment: There is a mistake in your answer. A or B will return A not if B is false, but if A is not false. Also, while True: and break are a good solution, mainly in Python, and it's completely acceptable.

Comment: I fixed my mistake. Thank you. For the break statement, my teachers always taught me not to use it too often so I never use it. But, I think in that case, it's totally acceptable. It's a very discussed point where to use and not to use break instructions.

Comment: ok all I had to do was change the if else statement and it worked. ty I spent ages. also your way of looping is very interesting I may use that :D  ty once again

Comment: @AlexisClarembeau My teacher tells us to never use 'break', but who really listens? An awesome command that is not used it a shame, isn't it? :)

Comment: I'm happy to have helped :) But, don't forget to mark the question as closed (with the green V mark) if I solved your problem ;)

But it's just a point of view. For me, goto and break are bad habbits as it can break the program flow :)

Comment: That's the idea of it, that's why it's called break! Many statements can 'break' program flow and that's what they're designed for - such as 'return'. You wouldn't say using 'return' in a function was a bad habit ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use "break" or "exit" to go out of the loop or the program. It's also generally better to use a larger condition that goes well in unexpected case (x<=0 or ans1 isn't YES rather than x==0 or ans1 is YES or ans1 is NO).

```
while True:
  # Code
  if ans1 not in ["Y", "YES"]:
    break # or exit
```

Then you would have no undefined behavior,  and also fewer condition to take care of : if it isn't "YES" or "Y", the program exit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a problem with this line:
    ans1 == ("Y" or "YES")

It is not similar to this line:

```
ans1 == "Y" or ans1 == "YES"
```

The second one is right, the first one is called `null coalescing`. That's not what you want. Basically, the idiom `x or y` returns x if x is not null, otherwise it returns y.
So basically you just check if ans1 is "Y" (not "YES")

You can check if a list of idioms contains yours this way:

```
if ans1 in ["Y", "YES"]:
```

And you can continue adding values to that list as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list and in statement:

```
x = 1
password = ""

while x == 1:        
# imagine there is some code here which works

 ans1 = input("\n\nTest a new password? ")
 ans1 = ans1.upper()

 print(ans1)

 if ans1 in ["Y","YES"]:
    x = x
 elif ans1 in ["N","NO"]:
    x = x + 10

print(x)
```

This ensures that the code works.